# All the results producing empty lists from geograpy

Tags: python, web-scraping

Below is a simple code to fetch all the cities from a URL specified :

```
import geograpy
url = 'https://www.netmagicsolutions.com/cloud-infrastructure-services'
places = geograpy.get_place_context(url=url)
print places.cities
```

But this is giving a empty list. Tried alot of solutions but couldn't find a proper solution. Any one having idea about this ? **or is there any python lib which can extract city/country from 'URL' ?**

Below is terminal snap :

```
runfile('D:/KJ/Nagesh/Downloads/WebScraping/geography.py', wdir='D:/KJ/Nagesh/Downloads/WebScraping')
[]
```

Comment: in this line of code `places = geograpy.get_place_context(text=text)` what is that `text` variable you are passing? is it defined else where? did you mean `places = geograpy.get_place_context(url=url)`?

Comment: I have modified the question. It should be url, but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with the current code. I think you can double check if the extractor is able to find the relevant places/entities or not.

You can always run the extractor to see what entities it has fetched from the URL. [Extractor code to get a better understanding of what is happening behind the scenes.](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy/blob/master/geograpy/extraction.py)

```
from geograpy import extraction
e = extraction.Extractor(url='https://www.netmagicsolutions.com/cloud-infrastructure-services')
e.find_entities()
```

You can also access all the places - by using `e.places`

Comment: Yes I have tried working with Extractor also, but its also giving the same result.

Comment: Can you try a different URL, does it happen with all the URLs?

Comment: I even tried with url="http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-26919928" which is there in the official doc of geograpy. All URLs are producing the same result. Is there any alternative way so that I can extract city/country from url only ?

Comment: can you try geograpy2 and see if the problem persists? Here is the link to geograpy 2 - https://github.com/Corollarium/geograpy2

Comment: !pip install geograpy2
Collecting geograpy2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geograpy2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for geograpy2
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: looks like they have stopped the geograpy2 support. Isn't working for me either.

Comment: is there any alternative ?

Comment: which version of Python are you using at the moment? Geograpy only works with Python2 and geograpy2 was introduced for Python3 but I think it didn't work out

Comment: I'm using PYTHON 2.7

Comment: I am sorry I don't have any alternative at the moment, had worked with the package a few years back, used to work seamlessly. I am afraid I can't assist you further.